# Implementing SessionAuthentication with django-rest-framework and Ajax?

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I have a RESTful API that only supports GET requests. It is running on the same domain as my front-end. All this is in Django 1.8 and DRF 3.2.2.

I then have a front-end pure-JS app that makes Ajax calls to the API. As an example, I have a form with some autocomplete fields. The fields will also be pre-filled, depending on the hash parameters that the page loads with. The values of these form fields are obtained by querying the API.

(For background, the application has no concept of users, and no need for any login or authentication methods, except that I want to make the API available only to my JS app.)

Now, I want to amend the API to use SessionAuthentication. I have two problems: (1) How do I set this up in Django? (2) How do I need to amend my JS code?

On question (1), I've updated my settings file to include SessionAuthentication:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

But right now, the API still seems to be available to anyone. I need it to be available *only* to my API.

On question (2), this is my current Ajax setup for a Select2 autocomplete field:

```
    ajax: {
            url: "/api/1.0/bnf_code/",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 50,
            data: function (params) {
              return {
                q: params.term,
                page: params.page

              };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                // do stuff
            },
            cache: true
        }
```

And this is the code to pre-fill the values of the autocomplete field.

```
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this
        });
```

How do I need to amend these, once I've got SessionAuthentication set up?

Answer (score 1):

## 1

You need to change the [permission policy](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

The default is `'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'`.

## 2

To do authentication on AJAX requests, add the `withCredentials` field to each AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: a_cross_domain_url,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true # <----
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves (1), now all results return "not authenticated". But how do I amend my Ajax to authenticate?

Comment: Also, you may have trouble with csrf.  Certainly in dev-mode, but also possibly in production.  You'll need to look up CSRF configuration.

Comment: Unless you're serving your front end with Django too. Then you're fine.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, the front-end is served with Django. Unfortunately even with the `xhrFIelds` set I get back a 403 error. The request header includes `Cookie:__atuvc=17%7C45%2C34%7C46; csrftoken=AC0V5tH6jxqRixEmD8pkyyA2kn7da9c0;`, but the same header seems to be present even when the `xhrFields` isn't set. NB this is all on localhost. Do I need to do something different?

Comment: Also, in case it's relevant, the API back-end and the front-end are on the same domain (localhost) and both are served with Django. And finally the body of the 403 response is `{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`. I get the same response if I navigate to the URL in the browser (which is as I'd expect).

Comment: Oooh.  `localhost`.  You need to use your network name or network IP.  Browsers don't save the `session` ID on localhost, for some reason.  You need to send the `session` field back to the server on each request.

Comment: Thanks once again! Sorry to be pathetic, but how do I send the session field back? Is it just `xhrFields['session'] = 'something'`?

Comment: `withCredentials:true` should send the cookie back to the server.  The cookie should include the session id.